# Zilog Z80 CPU family security

Tags: backdoor

According to this [Intel and AMD could have backdoors in their CPU's](http://wccftech.com/intel-possibly-amd-chips-permanent-backdoors-planted-nsa-updated-1/), but what about Zilog and z80 family?

I am mostly interested in the latest eZ80 , but also the original z80 and others.

**Are there any published information about backdoors in the Z80 chip family?**

I want to know that, because I am working on a "security" project that involve the eZ80 (directly from ZIlog, not the clones) and I am a little worried, because of the article about Intel and AMD.

Comment: I don't think that backdoors in chips is widely considered likely. The article you quote ends with `Disclaimer: The information in this article is not presented as a fact but as an opinion. It is up to the reader to decided what is fact and what is fable.`

Comment: Why are then Russians (Baikal) and others licensing chip designs from ARM (notice that ARM doesn't manufacture the chips itself as a manufacturer, they just do the research and sell/license the designs to manufacturers etc.) instead of using Intel and AMD chips? Perhaps, because they can ensure themselves that the other countries do not have some backdoor there and that they can potentionally include their backdoor in their version of ARM rocessor too ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z80 predates the era when networks were common, or processors had any security features at all.  It's hard to imagine what would constitute a back door, when the front door was wide open, and there was nothing 'out there' to knock on it.